# How to enable GyroSensors for Exoplayer 360 videos

Tags: android, kotlin, video, exoplayer

I am developing a custom player based on Exoplayer for playing VR videos. I was able to create a Simplified version using `SimpleExoPlayer` however, even though I move my device, the VR player doesn't rotate as it should.

I then went to try out the Exoplayer demo and it completely worked. However, I was unable to modify the code to fit my needs, so I had to start from scratch. As I mentioned, I was able to create a very simplified version. however, the gyro sensors are not rotating the video. I wonder, what I am missing.

Here is my `VRPlayerActivity`:

```
class VRPlayerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mp4VideoUri: Uri? = Uri.parse("https://theyouthbuzz.com/ytplayer/Seoul8KVR3DTrailer.mp4")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vrplayer)
        val player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        val playerView = findViewById<SimpleExoPlayerView>(R.id.player_view)

        // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
            this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "YouthBuzz")
        )
        // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
        // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
        val videoSource: MediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(mp4VideoUri)
        // Prepare the player with the source.
        // Prepare the player with the source.
        player.prepare(videoSource)
        (playerView.videoSurfaceView as SphericalGLSurfaceView?)!!.setDefaultStereoMode(
            C.STEREO_MODE_TOP_BOTTOM
        )

        playerView.player = player

    }
}
```

Here is my `activity_vrplayer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="._views.VRPlayer.VRPlayerActivity">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:surface_type="spherical_gl_surface_view"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because you forgot to call `playerView.onResume()` with the proper lifecycle hook methods, according to its javadoc:

> public void onResume()
>
> Should be called when the player is visible to the user and if
>   surface_type is spherical_gl_surface_view. It is the counterpart to
>   onPause(). This method should typically be called in
>   Activity.onStart(), or Activity.onResume() for API versions <= 23.

In fact if we dig into the `PlayerView` source code we can see that this calls the `onResume()` method of `SphericalGLSurfaceView` which conveniently calls `updateOrientationListenerRegistration()` to register with `android.hardware.SensorManager`

Likewise despite you would be implementing a simplified version you should call the counterpart methods and `player.release()`

Comment: yup definitely. I went on github later that day and posted the same question on exoplayer forum. The contributors there pointed this out to me. Added the methods and worked like a charm

Comment: so finally whats the answer for this can you please help me. when and how I should use onResume